# MySQL Unique Key for more columns not working

Tags: mysql, null, unique, multiple-columns

I am trying to make Names unique for the authors. But if I try,

```
create table author(author_id int auto_increment primary key, firstname varchar(20), middlename varchar(20), lastname varchar(20)) auto_increment = 1001;
alter table author add unique(firstname, middlename, lastname);
```

Example 1:

```
insert into author(firstname, middlename, lastname) values('Alice',null,null);
insert into author(firstname, middlename, lastname) values('Alice',null,null);

select * from author;

1001 | Alice     | NULL       | NULL
1002 | Alice     | NULL       | NULL
```

If I give all three name parts, it works fine.

Example 2:

```
insert into author(firstname,middlename,lastname) values('Alice','Bob','Charlie');
insert into author(firstname,middlename,lastname) values('Alice','Bob','Charlie');
>> Error...Duplicate
```

Why names with null is not considered?

How to make it unique even for Example 1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally 'no null is equivalent to another null', so in your case this is acceptable. This is a design for major db's.

You can check the below links:

1. [Oracle](https://community.oracle.com/thread/376915)
2. [Postgres](https://www.pgrs.net/2008/01/11/postgresql-allows-duplicate-nulls-in-unique-columns/)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of NULL, use empty string(''), so that your DML becomes,

```
insert into author(firstname, middlename, lastname) values('Alice','','');
insert into author(firstname, middlename, lastname) values('Alice','','');
>> Error: Duplicate Entry
```

Having null is unknown to MySql, for that reason we need this way. Thanks if anyone took effort but couldn't answer.